# Create Permissions for Shared Tables

Tags: oracle

I've created two users using the below statements using the System user. I want the ADMIN_USER to have all privileges and this user will create a set of tables. I have an external process that is pumping in data for two of my tables created by the ADMIN_USER. The question I have is if the ADMIN_USER creates all the table structures, how do I give EXTERNAL_USER the capability to read, update and insert into TABLE_A and TABLE_B only?  Would I run the grant statements when I'm logged in as ADMIN_USER or the SYSTEM user? I'm using Oracle 11g.

**Created both while logged in as SYSTEM User:**

```
create user "ADMIN_USER" identified by "p@ssword123";      
grant create session, grant any privilege to ADMIN_USER;

create user "EXTERNAL_USER" identified by "p@ssword321";
```

**Logged in as ADMIN_USER:**

```
GRANT create session, select, update, insert 
   ON TABLE_A
   TO EXTERNAL_USER;
GRANT create session, select, update, insert 
   ON TABLE_B
   TO EXTERNAL_USER;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it is terribly unlikely that you want to grant `ADMIN_USER` the `GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE` privilege.  The user doesn't require any privileges in order to grant object-level privileges on tables that the user owns.  The `ANY` privileges are terribly powerful.  A user that can grant any privilege to another user can make any user (including the user itself) a DBA.  That is not what you want.

Realistically, as `SYSTEM`, you want to grant the system privileges that you want the users to have.  As the object owner, you would then grant the object-level privileges.

As `SYSTEM`

```
CREATE USER admin_user 
  IDENTIFIED BY "p@ssword123"
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE tablespace_name
  QUOTA 10M ON tablespace_name;
CREATE USER external_user IDENTIFIED BY "p@ssword321";

GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE TO admin_user;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO external_user;
```

As `ADMIN_USER`

```
<<create the tables>>

GRANT select, insert, update
   ON table_a
   TO external_user;
GRANT select, insert, update
   ON table_b
   TO external_user;
```

A DBA should also be able to grant object-level privileges.  It's generally preferable to use the object owner account for that.